# Rest Api parameter wildcard

Tags: rest, http, get, wildcard

i try to get all products from a server, which begins with a "wo" for example. 
So i have this GET:

```
http://myUrl:9090/my/path/products?propertyKey=productname&propertyValue=wo*
```

But the result is empty. How can i add wildcards in the parameters?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure your server handles wildcard

Comment: i use the rest api from openfire, how can i check this?

Comment: Is that your REST API or you are just acting as client. If thats your server, you need to check its implementaion, else you need to consult with your REST API provider